# Why doesn't jQuery .blur() a readonly field?

Tags: jquery, readonly, blur

I am trying to do a .blur() on a form that has all the text fields in readonly mode.

I need to blur it because I am using jQuery dialog and when I open it it automatically focuses  the first readonly field in the form.

So I call $("#my_dialog input").blur(); but nothing happens, the input still has the focus.

Anybody knows why is this happening with readonly fields?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question and I hope it helps someone.

What I've done is to create a custom jquery function/plugin, named readOnlyBlur.

What it actually does is:

- removes readonly attribute if found
- blurs the input
- restores the readonly attribute

You can get the code from here:
https://gist.github.com/atrandafir/5991483

Just put it in a javascript file and load it after jquery like a normal plugin.

Then instead of calling $("#my_dialog input").blur(); simply call $("#my_dialog input").readOnlyBlur();

So, like I said, hope it helps someone since Stackoverflow is wiki-style :)

Comment: You can use `$("#my_dialog input").trigger('blur')`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.trigger('blur')` instead.

http://jsbin.com/unaduj/1/edit

Comment: This would trigger `blur` without the blur action.